# SQL Server TLS cert question

Tags: sql-server-2019

Does SQL Server 2019 support Unified Communications X509 certs?  These are certs that have multiple host names/subdomains on the same cert so they can be used for SSL/TLS on several VMs.

Comment: I would imagine so. As long as it provides Key Encipherment and Digtal Signature, and has the extended usage of Server Authentication it should work fine. Have you tried it?